# Proxy all traffic without matching the domain names in Haproxy

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, haproxy, transparentproxy

I'm using Haproxy in my VPS for stream some video content. with my current setup I need to mention each every domain in the front-end and back-end section in my Haproxy.conf file. if I need to watch 10 channels I need to add many domains. I only use this proxy for certain streaming site not for all the web traffic. I installed Dnsmasq on my openwrt router and I can point only necessary domains to my VPS. I need to add entry only for dnsmasq and I need Haproxy to proxy all the things dnsmasq throw it. can I configure something like wildcards in Haproxy configuration? or is there any other methods

My haproxy.conf like this

```
# Frontend for connections over port 80/http
frontend f_sni_catchall  
    mode http
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    log global
    option httplog
    option accept-invalid-http-request
    capture request  header Host len 50
    capture request  header User-Agent len 150

    use_backend b_sni_catchall      if { hdr(host) -i www.example.com }

    default_backend b_deadend

# Backend for handling connections over port 80/http
backend b_sni_catchall  
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option http-server-close


    server www.example.com www.example.com:80 check inter 10s fastinter 2s downinter 2s fall 1800
```

instead of using www.example.com I need to use something like this with the wild card

```
use_backend b_sni_catchall      if { hdr(host) -i *.com }

server*e.com *.com:80 check inter 10s fastinter 2s downinter 2s fall 1800
```

Using full domains in the config file is not possible due to DNS resolving issue. Haproxy wont start with some domain names. Other than that I need to set DNS pointing using dnsmasq or Bind. for do that I need haproxy to configured as forward all the domains what it get from the user

Comment: Please post the relevant block from you haproxy config and haproxy version.

Comment: @JimG. please check I updated my question with the Haproxy conf file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned before, to be conclusive we would need to know your version, since config format has changed between versions, but heres how i do it (1.6.3)

```
frontend web
    bind *:80 name http

    ### Wildcard ACL ###
    acl is_wild hdr_dom(host) -i wild

    ### Wildcard Backend###
    use_backend wild if is_wild


backend wild
    cookie  WILD_HTTP insert
    server  wild 10.1.1.1:80 cookie A check
```

As you may see, no * needed, anything that matches (ie wild.mydomain.com, mydomain.wild.com, something.mewild.com) will be send to this acl, and then will use the desired backend mapping.